# AliasMatch and RegEx

Tags: regex, apache, vhosts

I'm working with a centralized CMS on a dev server, the CMS is in `/var/www/central-cms`

The site (I've many sites) is accessible by this url: `http://web.localdomain.dev/site1/`.

How can I access the cms simply typing this url: `http://web.localdomain.dev/site1/cms`?

Maybe `AliasMatch` is the solution? Any help with the RegExp?

Example

`http://web.localdomain.dev/stackoverlow/`

`http://web.localdomain.dev/google/`

`http://web.localdomain.dev/yahoo/`

etc.

If I append a `/cms` to the url, this URL point to `/var/www/central-cms`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like a simple `Alias` directive would work:

```
Alias /site1/cms /var/www/central-cms
```

If this doesn't work, you may need to provide us with more details regarding your configuration.

If you want to accomplish this for multiple sites, you can use the `AliasMatch` directive.  You can look at the [AliasMatch documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) for more information, including some good examples, but in the end you'll end up with something like this:

```
AliasMatch ^/[^/]*/cms(.*) /var/www/central-cms$1
```

This means that an access to `/site1/cms/foo` will go to `/var/www/central-cms/foo`...and so will a request for `/site2/cms/foo`.

The expression `[^/]*` matches any number of characters other than `/`, which is important here so that the string `cms` appearing elsewhere in the URL doesn't cause problems.

Comment: Yes with the Alias directive works good, but what I do not want to do is to add many Alias for each site. In my example I've used site1 but the name is always variable. This is why I need to do it in a dynamic way. May be AliasMatch do the job or not?

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're trying to do.  Do *all* the sites point to `/var/www/central-cms`?  Or is there a relation between the site name and filesystem path?  Can you update your question with an example showing how you expect access to `/site2/cms` to behave vs. how `/site1/cms` behaves?

Comment: Exactly all the URL that end with `cms` example `/name_of_the_site/cms` point to `/var/www/central-cms`, no relation between site name and file system path. Ok I update my question with an example.